# Problems in C code

Tags: c, getchar

I am trying to make a simple calculator in Turbo C(I have my own reasons to why I use Turbo C now)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define P printf
int loop[] = {1, 1, 1, 1};
int num;
char input[64];
void main()
{
    int num1, num2;
    char x, y;
    while(loop[0] == 1)
    {
        clrscr();

        P("Hello!, This simple calculator will help you compute 2 numbers.");
        P("\nPress the corresponding key to choose the operation you will use.");
        P("\n\nA - (A)ddition");
        P("\nS - (S)ubtraction");
        P("\nM - (M)ultiplication");
        P("\nD - (D)ivision");
        P("\n\nAnswer: ");

        while(loop[1] == 1)
        {
            x = getchar();

            if(tolower(x) == 'a')
            {
                P("\nYou have chosen addition.");
                num1 = askForNumber("\n\nEnter 1st number: ");
                num2 = askForNumber("\nEnter 2nd number: ");
                P("\n\n%d + %d = %d", num1, num2, num1+num2);
            }
            else if(tolower(x) == 's')
            {
                P("\nYou have chosen subtraction.");
                num1 = askForNumber("\n\nEnter 1st number: ");
                num2 = askForNumber("\nEnter 2nd number: ");
                P("\n\n%d - %d = %d", num1, num2, num1-num2);
            }
            else if(tolower(x) == 'm')
            {
                P("\nYou have chosen multiplication.");
                num1 = askForNumber("\n\nEnter 1st number: ");
                num2 = askForNumber("\nEnter 2nd number: ");
                P("\n\n%d * %d = %d", num1, num2, num1*num2);
            }
            else if(tolower(x) == 'd')
            {
                P("\nYou have chosen division.");
                num1 = askForNumber("\n\nEnter 1st number: ");
                num2 = askForNumber("\nEnter 2nd number: ");
                P("\n\n%g* %g = %.2f", (float)num1, (float)num2, (float)(num1/num2));
            }
            else
            {
                P("\nYou have entered an invalid character!");
                P("\n\nAnswer: ");
                continue;
            }

            while(loop[2] == 1)
            {
                P("\n\nDo you want to do another calculation? Y/N: ");
                y = getchar();
                if(tolower(y) == 'y' || tolower(y) == 'n')
                {
                    loop[2] = 0;
                }
                else
                {
                    P("\nYou have entered an invalid character.");
                    continue;
                }
            }

            loop[1] = 0;
        }

        if(tolower(y) == 'y')
        {
            continue;
        }
        if(tolower(y) == 'n')
        {
            loop[0] = 0;
        }
    }
}

int askForNumber(const char *string)
{
    P("%s", string);
    while(loop[3] == 1)
    {
        fgets(input, (sizeof(input)/sizeof(input[0]))-1, stdin);
        if(sscanf(input, "%d", &num) != 1)
        {
            num = 0;
            P("Invalid number!");
            continue;
        }
        return num;
    }
}
```

I have these bugs:

1. After I finish a calculation, and press 'Y', it clears the screen non-stop.
2. After "Enter 1st number: ", the "Invalid number" shows up once even though I haven't typed anything yet(but i can still input a number and it will be saved to 'num1', "Invalid number just bugs me".
3. At the top where I am to input 'a' or 's' or 'm' or 'd' to choose an operation, if I put some letter except for that above, i get this

OUTPUT:

```
Answer: o

You have entered an invalid character!
Answer:

You have entered an invalid character!
Answer:
```

the error shows up twice, but i only typed once.

Comment: How many keys did you need to press to input a choice? (Hint: 2. You also pressed the return-key).

Comment: Please post a little code as possible.

Comment: EOF, just 1 key, then "Enter"

Comment: "Enter" aka "return". So, what do you think happens when you `getchar()` after "return" has been pressed?

Comment: `#define P printf` Really? come on lol

Comment: `void main()` should be `int main(void)`. Discard whatever book told you to use `void main()`; its author doesn't know C. (Yes, it's more complicated than that.)

Comment: @JaredBurrows just too many printf's to type lol

Comment: @KeithThompson thanks for the tip!

Comment: @NatsuMerlin: Code is typically read *many* more times than it's written. Shortcuts that save a few keystrokes are rarely worthwhile, especially if they make the code harder to read. (If you like, you can write `P` and then do a global search-and-replace in your editor.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When there are no characters in the input buffer, the `getchar` function blocks until the `return` key is pressed.  All keys, including `return`, are stored in the input buffer, then `getchar` returns the first character in the buffer.  The next call to `getchar` will immediately return the next character in the buffer.

So if you press 'y' then `return`, the first call to `getchar` returns the 'y' character, and the next returns a newline character, i.e. the `return` key.

You need to flush the input buffer each time you use `getchar` to skip over the newline:

```
do {
    c = getchar();
} while (c == '\n');
```

Answer (score -2):

You nedd #include ctype.h to lower is part of that library tolower uses this library and its nowhere in your code

Comment: It's true that the program *should* have `#include <ctype.h>`, but it's not relevant to the question -- and for pre-1999 C (remember the OP is using Turbo C), it works correctly due to the implicit declaration.